# Override MyAccountController Prestashop

Tags: controller, overriding, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm using PS 1.6.1.1 and i would like to override `MyAccountController` to add new var in my tpl file.

I create my file in `override/controllers/front/MyAccountController` with :

```
class MyAccountControllerCore extends FrontController
public function initContent()
{        
    $smarty = new Smarty;
    $smarty->assign('firstname', 'Doug');

    $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'my-account.tpl');
}
```

}

When i call `<span>{$firstname}</span>` in my tpl file, not work.

I removed `cache/class_index.php`

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with :

```
class MyAccountControllerCore extends FrontController
    public function initContent()
    {           
        $this->context->smarty->assign('firstname', 'Doug');
        Parent::initContent();
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: Yes, last answer helped me. Do you know if it possible to get customer groups in 'MyAccountController' ?

Comment: Yes add : 
$this->context->smarty->assign('listgroup', $this->context->customer->getGroups());

Comment: It work, thanks, another little question, is it possible in smarty to add if condition with php var ? For exemple {if {$groupe} == 1} ?

Comment: Yes, try : foreach ($this->context->customer->getGroups() as $listGroup)
{
    if ($listGroup['id_group'] == 1){
        
    }
}

Comment: I found a solution with     {foreach $customerGroups as $groups}
  {if {$groups['name']} == {$groupe}} thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the "global" smarty.
You should use:

```
$this->context->smarty->assign('firstname', 'Doug');
```

Comment: Hoo thanks you ! You saved me ... :) Do you know if it possible to get customer groups in 'MyAccountController' ?